# Splicing object into array in state with setState update immutability helper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm having trouble structuring my update helper and was wondering if anyone knew how to set this up. My state looks like this:

```
state = {
        array: [
            {
                1: { thing1: 'thing1', thing2: 'thing2' },
            },
            {
                2: { thing1: 'thing1', thing2: 'thing2' },
            },
            {
                3: { thing1: 'thing1', thing2: 'thing2' },
            }
        ]
};
```

And I'm wanting to take an object and replace a specific position in the array with it. So something that traditionally looks like:

```
const newObj = {
     newthing1: 'newthing1',
     newthing2: 'newthing2'
};

state.array.splice(0, 1, newObj);
```

Right now with the immutability-helper, I'm getting an error that prevState.array is not iterable when I try and update it with an index position. Any thoughts?

My setState function looks something like:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
                array: update(...prevState.array[1], {$splice: { 2: { newthing1: 'newthing1' }}})
            }))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a spread operator before prevState.array[1] inside update?  It takes an  array source as the first parameter

Comment: Also the syntax on splice is not correct, it takes an array of arrays that represent the values to splice on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to do, because your setState example looks to be using different values than your original `.splice`.  But I used your original splice as the example to go off of:

For reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html#nested-collections

```js
    state = {
            array: [
                {
                    1: { thing1: 'thing1', thing2: 'thing2' },
                },
                {
                    2: { thing1: 'thing1', thing2: 'thing2' },
                },
                {
                    3: { thing1: 'thing1', thing2: 'thing2' },
                }
            ]
    };

    const newObj = {
      newthing1: 'newthing1',
      newthing2: 'newthing2'
    };
    this.setState( prevState =>
      update(prevState, { array: { $splice: [[0, 1, newObj]] } })
    );
```

Honestly, that doesn't look right, because the objects are inconsistent.  I'm guessing you meant this:

```js
update(prevState, { array: { $splice: [[0, 1, {1: newObj}]] } })
```

Or if I go off your attempt at `update`, maybe this?:

```js
update(prevState, { array: { $splice: [[1, 1, {2: newObj}]] } })
```

To explain what it does:
  Starting from `prevState` object,
  First it traverses property `array`
  Then it iterates over a list of `splice` commands (there is only 1 in this example)
  Executes this splice:

```js
 [
   1, // starting index to splice at
   1, // length to splice out
   {2: newObj} // object(s) to insert
 ]
```

Comment: Yes, sorry - my original question is confused after looking at it again. Ignoring `newObj` and just going off my state structure. I'm wanting to simply replace array[0], or array[1] or whatever i need, with a completely new object at that index. so lets say my original object within the array is `{ 1: { thing: 'thing' }}`. I want to replace that with `{1: { anotherThing: 'anotherThing' }}`. Does that make sense?

Comment: If it's an object, it would be `{1: { $set: {  anotherThing: 'anotherThing' } }`.  If it is an array, it should be { $splice: [[1, 1, {anotherThing: 'anotherThing'} ]]

Comment: Interestingly its saying prevState is not defined. Also this is inside an onChange function. It should look like this yeah? `this.setState((prevState) => ({
                update(prevState, { array: { $splice: [[0, 1, { 1: newObj } ]]}})
            }))`?

Comment: Almost `this.setState((prevState) => update(prevState, { array: { $splice: [[0, 1, { 1: newObj } ]]}} ))`

Comment: `x => ({ obj: 1})` is equivalent to `(function(x) { return {obj: 1} }).bind(this)`,  the parantheses are kind of a small lazy man's hack to make it resolve the brackets as object notation instead of function closure brackets

Comment: Dude! It worked! Thank you. Although, now it is bringing up a new issue. Do you know what command I would use if I wanted to push the object to the array index instead of completely replace it? I'm using form inputs and event.target listeners to determine the index that I splice into and it turns out I actually need the the target.values to add to an object within the array rather than replace it with a completely new object. No worries if this is too much. You've done enough already! Thank you!

Comment: Just use $splice, but use 0 length, so `{ array: { $splice: [[index, 0, {obj: value} ]] }}`

Comment: BTW you should have made new questions for all these tasks, or a list of all these operations.  It definitely would be helpful for future googlers looking for how to work with immutability.

Comment: Ok gotcha - I've only been coding for a few months so still figuring out how all this works. Thanks for the advice and the help!

Comment: Sure thing.  Also if the answer helps you out you can click the green arrow to accept the answer.  Helps to keep Stackoverflow a well organized google searchable resource, the gold mine that it is.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use native methods.

```js
state = {
  array: [
      {
          1: { thing1: 'thing1', thing2: 'thing2' },
      },
      {
          2: { thing1: 'thing1', thing2: 'thing2' },
      },
      {
          3: { thing1: 'thing1', thing2: 'thing2' },
      }
  ]
};
const newObj = {
  newthing1: 'newthing1',
  newthing2: 'newthing2'
};
const index = 1 // could be any id

const newState = {array: state.array.slice(0, index).concat({[index]: newObj}).concat(state.array.slice(index+1))}
console.log(newState)
```